# Disable filter based on response

Tags: java, servlets, pdf-generation, servlet-filters

I have a client caching disabling filter which is mapped to all URLs.

Now I have to specifically disable the filter and allow caching when the response has anything other than html.

My current filter code is as follows:

```
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,s-maxage=0,must-revalidate,proxy-revalidate,private,max-stale=0,post-check=0");
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

**NOTE**: Just for people who want to know why I am doing this - We have some paged which generate **PDF**. We take this PDF File and flush to the output stream. In IE8, the flush code doesn't work and logs show that `the client closed the connetion immaturely...Cannot write to committed response...`. When caching is enabled, PDF get written to client normally; without any issue. A separate requirement of the existing app is to not allow caching of any page on the client.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817179/exclude-filter-from-certain-urls the second answer will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something as simple as this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    if(response.getContentType().indexOf("text/html")>-1){
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,s-maxage=0,must-revalidate,proxy-revalidate,private,max-stale=0,post-check=0");
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);
    }
}
```

It don't really disable the filter, but at least the filter don't do anything when the response is not html.

Comment: I tried to print the contentType but don't know why for all the responses I get the `contentType=null`. Are you sure that the filter works after the server produces the content?

Comment: For all requests, the `response.getContentType()` method return null, but while debugging, I see that `httpResponse.context.contentTypes = [application/binary, application/pdf]`. The said property is a HashSet. Can I access it in any way?

Comment: Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos. Actually I see that the doFilter was on top. Later it was edited. So I am returning it back to the working code and accepting the answer.

Comment: This should be correct, with 2 important points: (1) Since response is not a future predicitng machine, put the `if(...)` *after* `filterChain.doFilter()` :) (2) If the content of the response is longer than the response buffer, the headers will be sent and you will not be able to change them after `filterChain.doFilter()`. You should wrap the response in another that will cache the entire content and then, in the filter, unwrap and send it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just check in the doFilter() method whether the resource is cacheable or not. You can use the request URI, content-type or MIME type for that.

Comment: Request URI are around 15. That would slow the app down for every request. Content-type of response prints as null. MIME Type is something I am unable to access.

Comment: Actually I see the correct `contentType` while debugging in the property `httpResponse.context.contentTypes = [application/binary, application/pdf]`. I am unable to access this HashSet through the defined methods of the object.